# Alterar coluna com valor "null" com Dataanotation [Required] com migrations do entity framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

ola,

tentei fazer uma migrations e alterar uma propriedade que no banco de dados estava com valor "null" pois era permitido entrar dados assim. depois Tentei mudar para um DataNotation [Required] e o dotnet deu erro dizendo que eu não posso alterar pq já é nulo o valor. Como resolver isso?

Comment: *"pq já é nulo o valor"* preciso por um valor lá (pode ser um valor padrão), fazer um update ou apagar os registros

Answer (score 0):

descobri.basta na migration usar uma função migrationBuilder.Sql(“script sql fazendo update where coluna for null”);